# Display message instead of empty googlechart?

Tags: google-visualization

when there is no sufficient data to draw chart google chart api returning empty chart but i want to display my message instead of empty chart,i have searched and found this [How to show an Empty Google Chart when there is no data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937349/how-to-show-an-empty-google-chart-when-there-is-no-data)
  but i'm not able to find how to show my message instead of empty googlechart?

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? That question seems to answer how to test for empty data before drawing the chart, so I don't see where your issue could be.

Comment: iam passing two parameters to draw chart if one of the two variables is zero api returning emprty chart,iam able check whether a variable is zero or not with that i want to stop googlechartapi to return empty chart and display my message

Comment: What is the issue? Just put an "if" statement that draws the chart if the value isn't zero, otherwise to display your message. If you still can't figure it out, include your code!

Comment: ya,found it thanks for your help @jmac

Comment: [here is another option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38745704/5090771)