# How to display "No Data" message in the middle of chart area in column chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I am using ng-google-charts.js library to display a column chart.

If we have data then the column chart will render like this.[Column Chart with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf6kM.jpg)
[image]

If we don't have any data to display then the column chart should be rendered like this.
[Columns Chart with out data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUZDI.jpg)
[image]

I spent lot of time to find out the solution. But endup with no solution.

Can someone please help me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use an annotation to display *No Data Copy*

basically, check if the data table is empty
if so, add a row for the annotation
use an empty string so no label appears on the x-axis
use `0` as the value, so there is something to 'annotate'

```
if (emptyData.getNumberOfRows() === 0) {
  emptyData.addRows([
    ['', 0, null, 'No Data Copy']
  ]);
}
```

then change the `annotation.stem` to be `'transparent'`
and increase the `length` so that it appears in the middle of the chart

```
annotations: {
  stem: {
    color: 'transparent',
    length: 120
  }
}
```

if you don't want annotations when data *is* present,
set the annotation column value to `null`

see following working snippet, two charts are drawn to show the chart both with and without data

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // create empty data table
    var emptyData = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'Element', type: 'string'},
        {label: 'Density', type: 'number'},
        {role: 'style', type: 'string'},
        {role: 'annotation', type: 'string'}
      ]
    });
    var withData = emptyData.clone();

    var options = {
      // set annotation for -- No Data Copy
      annotations: {
        // remove annotation stem and push to middle of chart
        stem: {
          color: 'transparent',
          length: 120
        },
        textStyle: {
          color: '#9E9E9E',
          fontSize: 18
        }
      },
      bar: {groupWidth: '95%'},
      height: 400,
      legend: {position: 'none'},
      vAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
          min: 0,
          max: 30
        }
      },
      width: 600
    };

    // if no data add row for annotation -- No Data Copy
    if (emptyData.getNumberOfRows() === 0) {
      emptyData.addRows([
        ['', 0, null, 'No Data Copy']
      ]);
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_0'));
    chart.draw(emptyData, options);

    withData.addRows([
      ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', null],
      ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver', null],
      ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold', null],
      ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2', null]
    ]);

    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_1'));
    chart.draw(withData, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div_0"></div>
<div id="chart_div_1"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add no data message in the chart. So for example above if there is no data for the silver column display a message so you would still see the bar charts for copper, gold, platinum

Comment: how can I display only the Annotation in a Scatter Chart? I git it working, but it also displays a data point with the values '0'.

Comment: you must have a data point for the annotation to represent, but you could use a style column or the colors option to make the point transparent...