# Custom Checkbox Category Selector

Tags: google-visualization

I want to filter my Data Array by different categories. It is working, but it should pick the rows of multiple categories. if multiple checkboxes are checked. How can I implement this code?

Here is my code:

```
check_cells = function() {
  var values = [];
  if (document.getElementById("checkbox_pouch").checked == true) {
    values.push('pouch');
  }
  if (document.getElementById("checkbox_18650").checked == true) {
    values.push('18650');
  }
  if (document.getElementById("checkbox_21700").checked == true) {
    values.push('21700');
  }
  if (document.getElementById("checkbox_pouch").checked == false && document.getElementById("checkbox_18650").checked == false && document.getElementById("checkbox_21700").checked == false) {
    values.push('empty');
  }
  if (values.length > 0) {
    view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{
      column:2,
      test: function (value) {
        return (values.indexOf(value) > -1);
      }
      }]));
    }
  dashboard.draw(view, drawOptions);
  }
  else {
  view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{column:2}]));
  dashboard.draw(view);
  }
  }

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

      var drawOptions = {
        showRowNumber: false,
        allowHtml: true,    
      };


      // Inititial Draw of the dashboard.
      dashboard.draw(view, drawOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when filtering on multiple values,
you will need to combine those into one filter setting.
the data view will not let you have multiple filters on the same column.

in this case, you can use the `test` callback function, rather than the `value` key.

here, an array is used to gather the values,
and the `test` callback to filter the column...

```
check_pouch = function() {
  var values = [];
  if (document.getElementById("checkbox_pouch").checked == true) {
    values.push('pouch');
  }
  if (document.getElementById("checkbox_18650").checked == true) {
    values.push('18650');
  }
  if (values.length > 0) {
    view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{
      column:2,
      test: function (value) {
        return (values.indexOf(value) > -1);
      }
    }]));
  }
  dashboard.draw(view);
}
```

Comment: I set the checkboxes to be checked by default and all the data is shown. How can I display an empty chart when none of the boxes are checked?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38745704/5090771)...

Comment: I have one checkbox checked by default and when loading the page it should only display those values. But it displays both until i uncheck and check the box again. I tried it with an event listener (DOMContentLoaded, check_pouch) but the console says: Uncaught ReferenceError: check_pouch is not defined. Any tips?

Comment: are filtering the data table on the first draw? will you please update the question with the code?