# google graph how to display empty graph when there is no data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, charts, google-visualization

I have a google graph where it is working as expected when there is data

[image]

But when there is no data it is displaying a message as follows

`Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string`

[image]

Here is the code that I am trying out

```
function drawBarChar() {
    show('loading5', true);
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        'GraphId': 1,
        'startDt': $("#from-date").val(),
        'endDt': $("#to-date").val()
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {
            show('loading5', false);
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0, 1,
                {
                    calc: "stringify",
                    sourceColumn: 1,
                    type: "string",
                    role: "annotation"
                }
            ]);

            var options = {
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                colors: ["#6cc49c"],
                bar: { groupWidth: "65%" },
                legend: { position: "none" }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart($("#vesselGraph")[0]);
            chart.draw(data, options);
        },
        failure: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert(r.d);
        }
    });
}



public JsonResult LoadGraph(int GraphId, DateTime? startDt = null, DateTime? endDt = null)
{
    List<object> chartData = new List<object>
    {
       new object[]
       {
          "Name", "Count"
       }
    };
    DataTable table = db.GetAllFromDb("up_DashboardList", "@dashBoardId", GraphId,
            "@startDate", startDt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "@endDate", endDt.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); // when the table has no rows it is displaying that error message
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            chartData.Add(new object[]
            {
                row["TypeName"], row["DataCount"]
            });
        }
        return Json(chartData);
}
```

After @whitehat suggested

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, need to understand how `arrayToDataTable` works.
it uses the data provided in the array to determine each column type.

if only the column headings are provided,
there is no data to determine the types.
and it defaults both column types to string.

all the chart types in the `'corechart'` package expect the first series to be a number, date, something other than a string.
so we cannot use `arrayToDataTable` to create the data table,
if there is a chance of no data existing.

we must use the `DataTable` default constructor.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

then we can test the data array received to determine if data exists.
if no data exists, we can add a blank row to draw a blank chart.

in this example, we receive the data in the following format.

```
var r = [['Name', 'Count']];
```

we remove the first row / array to use as the column headings.

```
var cols = r.splice(0, 1);
cols[0].forEach(function (col, index) {
  if (index === 0) {
    data.addColumn('string', col);
  } else {
    data.addColumn('number', col);
  }
});
```

then determine if additional rows exist,
if not add a blank row.

```
if (r.length > 0) {
  data.addRows(r);
} else {
  data.addRow(['', null]);
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
var r = [['Name', 'Count']];

google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  var cols = r.splice(0, 1);
  cols[0].forEach(function (col, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
      data.addColumn('string', col);
    } else {
      data.addColumn('number', col);
    }
  });
  if (r.length > 0) {
    data.addRows(r);
  } else {
    data.addRow(['', null]);
  }

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
  }]);

  var options = {
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
    colors: ["#6cc49c"],
    bar: { groupWidth: "65%" },
    legend: { position: "none" }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart($("#vesselGraph")[0]);
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="vesselGraph"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38745704/5090771) is another example that uses an annotation to display "no data"...

Comment: Hi I am seeing 0.0 0.2 like that when I change as suggested instead is it possible to display no data

Comment: Posted the output in question

Comment: you don't want the x-axis or any gridlines? why draw the chart at all? if no data, just don't draw...?

Comment: Hmm let's say initially the data binded and based on condition I want to clear how can I do that

Comment: save a reference to the chart, if no data after chart was drawn initially, use `clearChart()` method...