# Google Charts (gague) display when no value in database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to display google chart (gauge) when there is no values in my database.

My idea for doing this is to insert a dummy value in an array to display the chart and once values are added to the database overrides it.

**postData.php**:

```
<?php require 'conn.php';?>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sensors ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die ($conn->error);

// create data array
$data = [];
$data[] = [["label"=>"Label","type"=>"string"],["label"=>"Value","type"=>"number"]];
 
// output data of each row
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc() {
   $data[] = ["Temp", (float) $row["temp"]];   
}

// write data array to page
echo json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$result->free();
$conn->close();
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<script>
    google.charts.load('current', {
        packages: ['gauge']
    }).then(function () {
        var options = {
            width: 400, height: 400,
            redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
            yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
            minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        drawChart();

        function drawChart() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'postData.php',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (jsonData)     {
                   // use response from php for data table
                  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
                  chart.draw(data, options);

                  // draw again in 5 seconds
            
                   window.setTimeout(drawChart, 5000);
            });
        }
    });
</script>

<div id="chart_div" class="chart_hum" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by referencing this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742523/how-to-display-no-data-message-in-the-middle-of-chart-area-in-column-chart) and adding this code. Instead of doing in PHP using an array, I used JavaScript to add the dummy value and it gets overridden once data are inserted in to the database. Hope this maybe useful to someone in the future.

```
 function drawChart() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'postData.php',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (jsonData)     {
                   // use response from php for data table
                  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
                   // added part
                    if (data.getNumberOfRows() === 0) {
                   data.addRows([
                       ['Temp', 0]
                   ]);
            }
                  chart.draw(data, options);

                  // draw again in 5 seconds
            
                   window.setTimeout(drawChart, 5000);
            });
        }
```